Improving Scatter Plot Aesthetics in Julia
I have the following code that generates the following image.
res = model(Float32.(rand(hparams.noise_model, 1000)))
res = Float32.(rand(hparams.noise_model, 1000))

scatter!(res[1, :], res[2, :]; markersize=2.0, legend=:none, color=:green)



I would like to know how I can achieve something more similar to this.


https://discourse.julialang.org/t/help-to-perform-scatter-density-plot-with-plots-jl/72790/6

your code is not reproducible please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  and update the code so quations can be answered and are useful for the others

It's not clear which plotting library you are using, it seems to be perhaps Plots.jl or Makie.jl. Please specify. An additional tip: instead of writing Float32.(rand(...)) you can directly generate Float32 random values with rand(Float32, ...)

I am using Plots.jl

It seems that there isn't anything wrong with the scatter plot aesthetics, but that you are looking for a different kind of plot. You basically want a heatmap, where each pixel has a value proportional to the number of values that are inside or close to this pixel. So you can create a matrix, then for each element in the matrix calculate the relevant number, and then plot the matrix using the heatmap function.
